# Se suprimen espacios en respuesta JSON

Tags: php, json, api

Hice una "api" muy sencilla en PHP, ingresar una consulta y devuelve una respuesta en formato JSON. Y pues en mi servidor local funciona bien, pero al subirlo a mi servidor web la respuesta suprime los espacios:
Así veo el JSON en localhost:

```
{"word":"hola","def":"\nhola\n\nVoz expr.; cf. ingl. hello, al. hallo.\n1. interj. U. como salutaci\u00f3n familiar.\n2. interj. p. us. U. para denotar extra\u00f1eza, placentera o desagradable. U. t. repetida.\n3. interj. desus. Era u. para llamar a los inferiores.\n\r\nFuente: RAE\r\n\r\n\r\nlxndr"}
```

Y así en el servidor:

```
{"word":"hola","def":"holaVoz expr.; cf. ingl. hello, al. hallo.\n1. interj. U. comosalutaci\u00f3nfamiliar.\n2. interj. p. us. U. paradenotarextra\u00f1eza, placenteraodesagradable. U. t. repetida.\n3. interj. desus. Era u. parallamaralosinferiores.\n\r\nFuente: RAE\r\n\r\n\r\nlxndr"}
```

Como pueden observar dentro de "def" suprime espacios.
Adjunto las versiones de php detalladas que uso en cada lado (7)
Local:[image: PHP ver Local]

Servidor: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDITADO

Código que obtiene el html y extrae "def"

```
$dic_file->loadHTML($html); //Carga el HTML
libxml_clear_errors(); //omite errores yucky html

$dic_xpath = new DOMXPath($dic_file);

//obtener "article's" con su id
$dic_row = $dic_xpath->query('//article[@id]');

if($dic_row->length > 0){ //Si existe definicion se codifica a json
    foreach($dic_row as $row){
        $def = $row->nodeValue;

        break;
    }

}
```

Arma el array, lo codifica en JSON y muestra

```
$json = array('word' => $word, 'def' => $def.'Fuente: RAE');

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que enseñes parte del codigo donde se suscita el error para poder analizarlo y darte una solucion

Comment: @ivanhernandezaguilar Actualicé y puse parte del código.